pdfplumber ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified procedure could not be found
So I am converting text into speech using pdfplumber for extracting text, but I am getting error.
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.\_rust import exceptions as rust_exceptions
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing \_rust: The specified procedure could not be found.

Also I asked chat-gpt it tell install rust. Do I really need to download that?
import pdfplumber as pdfplumber

import tkinter as tk


def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    text = ""
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    return text


t = extract_text_from_pdf("game_doc.pdf")
print(t)


I encountered an issue while trying to connect with a Snowflake database, which uses the cryptography package as a dependency. To resolve the problem, I downgraded the cryptography package from version 41.0.8 to 41.0.7.
This solution worked for me, and I hope it helps others facing a similar issue.

pip install cryptography==41.0.7 fixed this issue for me on Python 3.9.0, thanks.
